# Azure FHIR Proxy - cannot access through Postman

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, azure-authentication

I have created an instance of Azure API for FHIR with an Azure FHIR proxy following this tutorial:

https://github.com/microsoft/health-architectures/tree/master/FHIR/FHIRProxy##configuration

I am able to browse to the proxy URL through a browser after being prompted to log in to view the metadata as shown below:

[FHIR Meta data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKqJ1.png)

However, when trying to access it through the Postman API tool I keep getting the same error:

**You do not have permission to view this directory or page.**

I have tried generating an authorization Bearer token using the following:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \   
--form 'grant_type="client_credentials"' \
--form 'client_id="{CLIENT_ID}"' \
--form 'client_secret="{CLIENT_SECRET}"' \
--form 'resource="{MY PROXY RESOURCE ID}"'
```

The authorization token looks fine, but when adding it to my API call it errors as shown below:

[API error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVAtw.png)

Does anyone have any idea how I can successfully call my API with a proper authorization token that works or know a tutorial that actually explains this part of the process?
The tutorial does not give much information.

EDIT:
**WWW-authenticate-header:**

Bearer realm="func-fhir-proxy-2.azurewebsites.net" authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/000000/oauth2/authorize" resource_id="0000"

Thanks

Comment: It is hard to know without being able to see the www-authenticate header or the actual error message. In general though, the token should not be needed at all for the metadata endpoint, so I am not sure that is a good indication that your token is working.

Comment: Hi @michaelhansen I have added the www-authenticate-header please see edit

Comment: I find the `resource_id="0000"` a bit puzzling here. I will try to see if I can loop in the person who did the proxy. The right thing to do would probably be an issue on that repo. This is not related to the FHIR service itself but to the proxy.

Comment: How do you use the token?

Comment: Hi, that resource id has been blanked out by me, the correct one is: https://func-fhir-proxy-2.azurewebsites.net. I have also tried: eb239a3e-bff6-4842-8073-d56019e92de5 @MichaelHansen